# Does $(5,X^2+1)=(5)+(X^2+1)$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let consider $\mathbb Z[X]$. First, do we agree that this ring is not principal (and even not UFD ?).

Now, I'm tring to show that $(5,X^2+1)/(5)\cong (X^2+1)$. So, to me $(5,X^2+1)=(5)+(X^2+1)$, is it true ? If yes, I get that $$(5,X^2+1)/(5)=5\mathbb Z[X]+(X^2+1)\mathbb Z[X]+5\mathbb Z[X]=(X^2+1)\mathbb Z[X]+5\mathbb Z[X]=(5,X^2+1),$$
where is my mistakes ?

Comment: $(a,b)=(a)+(b)$ ins any ring $R$.

Comment: Your mistake seems to be that you've conflated the notion of "ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(5)$" with the notion of "ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$".

Comment: Although... after thinking about it, I can imagine a notation for doing such arithmetic here what you wrote does actually make sense -- and in that case your mistake is that you haven't yet computed what the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(5)$ generated by (the class of) $X^2 + 1$ is.

Comment: ${\Bbb{Z}[x]}$ is not a PID, but it is most certainly a UFD, since polynomial rings over UFDs are UFDs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a,b)=(a)+(b)$ is true for any ring.

"where is my mistakes ?" You've changed which ring your ideals are part of. $(5,X^2+1)/(5)$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]/(5)$, while $(5,X^2+1)$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]$, and as such the two ideals aren't immediately comparable. The intermediate terms in your calculation could be in either ring, which is probably where the confusion comes in.